# Move PDF File to Another File Folder Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory, movefile

I tried this code below (shout-out to source provider) and now I want to add a little extra code, however I can't get f.Move function to work. In other words, I want to move PDF files from one folder to another file folder. Any suggestions?

```
 Dim origWB As Workbook
                    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
                    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
                
                Set origWB = ActiveWorkbook
                Dim wb As Workbook
                Dim myPath As String
                Dim myFile As String
                Dim myExtension As String
                Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
                
                'Optimize Macro Speed
                  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                  Application.EnableEvents = False
                  'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                        myPath = "L:\TEST FOLDER"
    
            NextCode:
                  myPath = myPath
                  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
                
                'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
                  myExtension = "*.pdf*"
                
                'Target Path with Ending Extention
                  
                Dim Rngemployees As Range
                Dim employee
                Dim numrows As Long
                Dim DOCKET As Workbook
                Dim Fab As String
                Dim TrackingNumberRange As Range
                Dim I
                Dim Ii As String
                Dim NumrowsManual45DaysRM As Integer
                Dim EfilePath As String
                
                NumrowsManual45DaysRM = Sheets("Manual45days").Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row
                
                
                Set TrackingNumberRange = Sheets("Manual45days").Range("H2:H" & NumrowsManual45DaysRM)
                
                Dim fso As Object
                Dim Fldr As Object
                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set Fldr = fso.getfolder(myPath).Files
                Dim f As Object
                'Loop through each Excel file in folder
                
                For Each f In Fldr
                
                myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
                
                If Len(Dir$(myPath & myFile)) > 0 Then
                
                     SetAttr (myPath & myFile), vbNormal 'This will probably allow you to modify the path of the file
                End If
                
                Debug.Print f.Name
                For Each I In TrackingNumberRange.Cells
                    Ii = I.Value
                    Ii = Replace(I, " ", "", 1, 3, vbBinaryCompare)
                    If f.Name = Ii & ".pdf" Then
                        Sheets("Manual45Days").Range("A" & I.Row) = "Signature Received"
                        EfilePath = Sheets("Manual45Days").Range("T" & I.Row).Value
                        EfilePath = Replace(EfilePath, "  ", " ")
                        Debug.Print EfilePath
                        
                        f.Move (EfilePath)  ''This line I am having Trouble with'''
                        
                        Debug.Print I.Row
                    End If

                Next
                
                Next f
                
                
                'Message Box when tasks are completed
                  MsgBox "Task Complete!"
                
ResetSettings:
                  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

ThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanksThanks
Thanks
Thanks
Thanks
Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, I found the answer and it worked :)
All I had to do is add a "" to the end of my desired destination path as below:

```
EfilePath = Replace(EfilePath, "  ", " ") & "\"
                        Debug.Print EfilePath
                        f.Move EfilePath
```